# Contact_ID who have not request for assistance since last 6 months and who has "AX" in his contact_ID

Tags: sql, sql-server, subquery

I have service desk database (SQL Server 2008) and two tables are:

**Contact:** Contact_ID, Contact_FullName

**Ticket:** Ticket_ID, Title, Open_Time, Contact_ID

I am find the people(Contact_ID) who have **not** requested for assistance **since last 6 months** and who has **"AX"** in his **contact_ID**.

Comment: What have you tried to do? I think this can be done with a select where statement on the ticket table.

Comment: I tried Gordon and Spencer query, but both query gives me different results. Not sure which one is correct.

Comment: You will need to look into the data then. Get all of the people that are in Gordon's query that isn't in Spencers and see if they should be there or not. I personally think Gordon's looks neater and it should do what you are asking.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with an aggregation query:

```
select t.contactid
from ticket t
where t.contactid like '%AX%'
group by t.contactid
having max(opentime) < dateadd(month, -6, getdate());
```

If you want the contact information, then you can use `join`, `exists`, or `in` to fetch it from that table.

Comment: I ran your query I got 10017 results and per Spencer query I got 3518 .

Comment: @user470091 . . . My first guess is that `ticket` has contacts that are not in the `contacts` table.

Answer (score 0):

Try this query:

```
SELECT contact_id, contact_name
FROM contact
WHERE contact_id LIKE '%AX%'
AND contact_id NOT IN
(
 SELECT DISTINCT contact_id
 FROM ticket
 WHERE open_time >= DATEADD(month, -6, GETDATE())
)
GROUP BY contact_id, contact_name
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, but why I am getting duplicates?

Comment: I ran your query I got 3518 results and per Gordon' query I got 10017. Confused which one is correct :(

Comment: I would think mine is. My reasoning is that Gordon's query will return all contacts who opened a ticket over 6 months ago. While my query will return all contacts who have not opened a ticket in the past 6 months.

Comment: Spencer, I manually check in the application but still found records which were created like this one created on 2017-08-11 13:30:17.000 with AX00002465 contact ID

Comment: Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 10
The multi-part identifier "c.contact_id" could not be bound.
Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 10
The multi-part identifier "c.full_name" could not be bound.

Comment: Yes sorry I forgot to remove the c. in the group by, try now.

Comment: 0 rows (not return a single record)

Comment: Yes, because we do have many AX contact id which they have not request for assistance in last six months. I can manually find the records.

Comment: I this supposed to be an answer to a question? Where is the question?

Comment: What is the column datatype for open_time?

Comment: open_time datetime

Comment: How many results does this return? : SELECT DISTINCT contact_id  FROM ticket WHERE open_time >= DATEADD(month, -6, GETDATE())

As compared to just: SELECT DISTINCT contact_id FROM ticket

Comment: SELECT DISTINCT contact_name FROM INCIDENTSM1 WHERE open_time >= DATEADD(month, -6, GETDATE()) -- 12683 rows

Comment: SELECT DISTINCT contact_name FROM INCIDENTSM1 -- 22710 rows

Comment: What about SELECT DISTINCT contract_ID FROM contact WHERE contact_id LIKE '%AX%'

Comment: SELECT DISTINCT contract_ID FROM contact WHERE contact_id LIKE '%AX%' -- 4786

Comment: And try: SELECT DISTINCT contact_id FROM contact WHERE contact_id LIKE '%AX%' -- 4786 AND contact_id NOT IN ( 
SELECT DISTINCT contact_id FROM contact WHERE open_time >= DATEADD(month, -6, GETDATE()))

Comment: I believe you accidentally have contact table in 2nd query. I changed it to the ticket table and return no row.

Comment: I'm sorry, I really don't know how to help from here. I really do think that that query answers your question, I hope at least it helps!